# Convert Denary to Binary problem (python)

Tags: python, function, input, binary, output

Im stuck on a problem where I have to write a function that converts a denary number into a binary number using the repeated division by two algorithm. Steps Include:

-The number to be converted is divided by two.

-The remainder from the division is the next binary digit. Digits are added to the front of the sequence.

-The result is truncated so that the input to the next division by two is always an integer.

-The algorithm continues until the result is 0.

Please click the link below to see what the output should be like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pifUO.png

This is My code so far:

```
def dentobi(user):
  denary = user
  divide = user / 2
  remainder = user % 2
  binary = remainder
  
  while user != 0:
    print("Denary:", denary)
    print("Divide by 2:", divide)
    print("Remainder:", remainder)
    print("Binary:", binary)
    break
user = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
dentobi(user)
```

My output when a number doesn't have remainder is:

```
Please enter a number: 20
Denary: 20
Divide by 2: 10.0
Remainder: 0
Binary: 0
```

Output when the number does have a remainder:

```
Please enter a number: 20
Denary: 20
Divide by 2: 10.0
Remainder: 0
Binary: 0
```

This is one part of what I wanted to happen however I need this to iterate over and over again until the actual value reaches zero.

I need some help in coding the remainder to go in the front each time, appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for this type of solutions:

from math import floor

```
def denary_to_binary(num: int):
    print(f"num: {num}, num / 2: {floor(num / 2)}, remainder: {num % 2}")
    if num <= 1:
       return str(num)
    
    return denary_to_binary(floor(num / 2)) + str(floor(num % 2))

print(denary_to_binary(26))
print(denary_to_binary(20))
```

Which yields:

```
num: 26, num / 2: 13, remainder: 0
num: 13, num / 2: 6, remainder: 1
num: 6, num / 2: 3, remainder: 0
num: 3, num / 2: 1, remainder: 1
num: 1, num / 2: 0, remainder: 1
11010
num: 20, num / 2: 10, remainder: 0
num: 10, num / 2: 5, remainder: 0
num: 5, num / 2: 2, remainder: 1
num: 2, num / 2: 1, remainder: 0
num: 1, num / 2: 0, remainder: 1
10100
```